# IE Get Access To All Sites

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am using a Macro Excel functions to load web pages, but many websites are no longer supporting the IE, the main web browser working on VBA.

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Visible = 0

URL = "http://website/"

ie.Navigate URL


State = 0

Do Until State = 4
DoEvents
State = ie.readyState
Loop
```

would the problem be solved if i installed IE11 or MS Edge?

Comment: What error do you get ?, please post some code so we can help because maybe it's a library calling for newest IE versions or any other code setting your missing.

Comment: Yes installing the latest and recommended version of any web browser that web sites identify as unsupported would help. You cannot install Edge. IE11 and Edge are pre-installed on Windows 10 computers only. You should update your windows 7 or 8.1 to IE11 and run windows update also to install any pending security updates for your IE11 and other Windows software.